# Key mapping in GDB

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb, binutils

Is it possible to define an arbitrary key combination to a command in GDB? I would like to know if there is something like the VIM map command. For example, I would like to map  to next,  to step, and so on..

Answer (score 3):

To map keys in gdb (tested on gdb/cygwin/win7)

```
1. Start gdb
2. Find the key generated by F7, Press C-v F7
   (gdb) ^[[18~
3. vi ~/.inputrc
   # Map F7 to next
   "\e[18~": "n\n" 
4. Restart gdb, and now F7 will be mapped to "next\n"
```

More Info here https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html

```
# Sample ~/.inputrc
$if Gdb
"\e[23~": "next\n # [F7] next.\n"  
"\e[A":  "# Up key\n"
"\e[B":  "next\n # [Down]  next line.\n"
"\e[C":  "step\n # [Right] step into func.\n"
"\e[D":  "finish\n # [Left] to finish.\n"
$endif
```

gdb has builtin text based gui called TUI mode, even works in cygwin/win7, Sample usage:

```
> g++ -Wall -g -lm -std=c++14 hello.cpp
> gdb -tui a.exe
```

Press C-x s .. for Single key mode

```
    q - quit, exit SingleKey mode.  
    c - continue
    d - down
    f - finish
    n - next
    r - run 
    s - step 
    u - up 
    v - info locals 
    w - where
```

More info https://volse.anduin.net/rabalder/2015/06/01/gdb-tricks-text-based-ui.html and here https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_19.html

Answer (score 2):

GDB uses GNU readline to read the input. Documentation [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readline) (or just type `man readline`).

In particular, pay attention to the example of how to bind F1 to insert text `Function key 1`.