# Key mapping in LLDB

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lldb, key-bindings, keymapping

Is there any way to specify key mappings in LLDB? Similar to [*Key mapping in GDB*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090720/key-mapping-in-gdb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn out that LLDB is using `libedit` (a.k.a. Editline) similar to GDB using [GNU Readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline). So instead of `~/.inputrc` we use `~/.editrc`. I can’t find the official manual, but Debian manual page [editrc(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/libedit2/editrc.5edit.en.html) and [editline(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/libedit2/editline.7edit.en.html) is helpful here. Example configuration:

```
bind "\e[5~" ed-search-prev-history # PgUp
bind "\e[6~" ed-search-next-history # PgDn
```